# Use of reference operator & in returning from function in c++

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference

I am getting confused here in the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;
double vals[] = { 10.1, 12.6, 33.1, 24.1, 50.0 };

double& setValues(int i)//if i remove the &operator, i get an error, why ?
{
    return vals[i]; // return a reference to the ith element
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Value before change" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        cout << "vals[" << i << "] = ";
        cout << vals[i] << endl;
    }
    setValues(1) = 20.23; // change 2nd element
    setValues(3) = 70.8; // change 4th element
    cout << "Value after change" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        cout << "vals[" << i << "] = ";
        cout << vals[i] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If i remove the & operator in the function

```
double& setValues(int i);
```

i get the error as 'l-value required as the left operand of the assignment'
Is that means the value vals[i] should be placed in the right? and with & operator this part becomes l-value ?

Comment: Think of it as `int f() { return 1; } int main(){ f() = 2; return 0; }`. That won't work and is equivalent to what you wrote when you left out the `&`.

Comment: that means here the function is missing the & operator in the return type

Comment: http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/12/15/understanding-lvalues-and-rvalues-in-c-and-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a variable or an array, giving them names, they have an area of memory set aside for them to be located in.

```
double vals[] = { 10.1, 12.6, 33.1, 24.1, 50.0 };
```

Each element of that array has a distinct memory address.

Your function, without the `&` reference declarator will simply return a *copy* of the value in the array:

```
double setValues(int i); // return a copy of a value from the array
```

The problem with this copy is that it has not been given a permanent place to live in memory. It is what we call a *temporary* value and it lives only as long as the expression that creates it. Once the expression is over the *temporary* value is destroyed.

So:

```
double d = setValue(3); // okay
```

Despite the function name not being very appropriate the compiler allows this because the *temporary copy* of the value from the array is stored in the permanent(ish) location called `d` before the *temporary* is destroyed.

So it is useful to allow expressions that create *temporaries* to exist on the *right hand side* of an assignment where their values can be *captured* by the *left hand side* of the assignment.

But the reverse is not true:

```
setValue(3) = 70.8; // not allowed
```

The reason being that `setValue(3)` returns a *temporary copy* of the value in the array that will be immediately destroyed after the assignment. So it makes no sense to allow such a *temporary value* to be written to if its value will be deleted immediately after.

Also, if the compiler was to allow an assignment to such a temporary it would have to set aside actual memory for it (rather than just a CPU register) and there would be many places when the compiler would lose the opportunity to deal with the temporary much more efficiently.

When you change the function to return a *reference* by using the *reference* declarator that all changes:

```
double& setValues(int i); // return access to the value in the array
```

What that returns is access to the actual value in the array itself. This is *not* a temporary value but a permanent(ish) value resident in main memory.

So now it makes sense for the compiler to allow you to change its value because it won't be destroyed after the expression ends but it will continue to exist until the array itself is destroyed.

```
setValue(3) = 70.8; // now it is good - changes the array itself
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is that means the value vals[i] should be placed in the right?

No. `vals[i]` can be both left operand and right operand of assignment operator. It is `double` *value* returned from the function that cannot be left operand of the operator.

> with & operator this part becomes l-value ?

This `&` is not an operator but a part of declarator. With `&`, a *reference* is returned from the function and you can use it as left operand of the operator.

Comment: that means &vals[i] can be used along left side of the expression!

Comment: @BhavyaDhiman: That's something completely different. That's a different meaning of `&`.

Comment: `&` has too many meanings. Additionally declaring references is one of the few cases where the declaration syntax doesn't follow the expression syntax (as opposed to pointers, for example), partly because there simply isn't a "reference operator". In all reality I think one could as well do without an address operator: `int i, *pi = i;` is perfectly clear. Probably the same is true for the dereferencing operator: `int k = 0, *pi = k, i = pi;` would simply assign 0 to i. Algol68 performs these (de)reference exercises automatically.

Comment: @BhavyaDhiman No, the result of `&` *operator* is *prvalue*, which is like `100`, according to [N3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) 5.3.1 Unary operators, so it cannot be used as left operand of assignment operator, which have to be *lvalue* according to [N3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) 5.17 Assignment and compound assignment operators